# Difficulty in hiding ad when the internet connection is not available

Tags: android

I am making an application in which i am providing an ad.I want to hide the ad when the internet connection is not available.But i was not able to do that.This is the code which i used to achieve that result.Please tell me what is the problem with the code.

```
AdView myAddView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            myAddView.setVisibility(8);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
|| !ni.isAvailable() || !ni.isConnected()
```

Second reason: you can hide container of Ad ( for example), because it can force show himself, but can't show it's parent.

And use `View.GONE` instead of hardcoded "8".

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: please tell me how to hide the container of the ad.can you please give me one or two lines of code.

Comment: in layout xml file wrap Ad by <LinearLayout>, in code get this LinearLayout by it's id.